# robotframework unable to use timeout=20s

Tags: robotframework

I'm want to use timeout while waiting page contains element but exeuction complaint error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to compile '//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Close navigation drawer"] timeout=20s
```

**test case:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library  AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${compose-new-mail}    id=android.widget.ImageButton
${navigation-drawer}    //android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Close navigation drawer"]
${navigation-drawer2}    //android.widget.ImageButton[contains(@content-desc, "Close navigation drawer")]

*** Test Cases ***
Open Application
   Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    deviceName=2529b29c9b0c7ece    appPackage=com.test.aa.work.cac    appActivity=com.test.aa.activity.MailActivityEmail    automationName=Uiautomator2    noReset=true    userProfile=10   optionalIntentArguments=--user 10 -n "com.test.aa.work.cac/com.test.aa.activity.MailActivityEmail"
   Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${navigation-drawer} timeout=20s
   appiumlibrary.tap    ${compose-new-mail}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied/pasted your code exactly, then there is a missing space before `timeout`.

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${navigation-drawer} timeout=20s
```

should be

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${navigation-drawer}  timeout=20s
```